# Hebrew typeface that appears to be a Latin typeface at first glance

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

The famous font Sefard is a “faux Hebrew” Latin font: It looks like Hebrew script at first glance on account of incorporating typical Hebrew typographic elements, but actually it is a Latin-script font.

[image: Sefard example]

I am looking for the opposite, i.e., a faux-Latin Hebrew font: a font that looks like the Latin script font but in reality, is Hebrew. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Mod’s notice: I cleared the comments since I think they have now been addressed.

Comment: User's notice: Thanks! `:)` @Wrzlprmft